# Should user Controls be used for ListBox in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am working on windows phone apps. When I was reading about improving the performance of an app, I came across this [msdn blog](http://marker.to/2608T0) which is concentrated on silver light performance for ListBox in windows phone. It suggests that we should not use User Controls in data template. (I have marked the text in the link in two areas. which i felt doubtful)

Now my question is  can I create a list of user control objects and add to a ItemsControl say ListBox which is in the view.? Will the control's XAML be considered as a Resource and parse it every time ? (like it is told in the blog). How can I test that? I asked in the same blog a week ago but the question did not get published there.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ListBox some times and in fact, its performance is poor. However, I use to create DataTemplateItem instead of UserControls since I have not needed UserControl.

About your questions: You can create a list of UserControls and add them to ListBox, however consider using DataTemplates instead. I guess that control's XAML is parsed every time (but not sure). To test it, just  check this [link](http://www.cjcraft.com/blog/2011/01/21/WP7DevTip004ApplicationCurrentHostSettings.aspx).

cheers,